# raspberry pi has a error with kinect

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, kinect

I have a problem with use Kinect on a Raspberry Pi.
when I run my program with libfreenect, I have an error to run the program, after then I execute more again and more again and suddenly system has work and my kinect wake-up and runs my program.
please help. my error is :

```
send_cmd: Input control transfer failed (18)
freenect_fetch_reg_const_shift: send_cmd read 18 bytes (expected 8)
freenect_camera_init(): Failed to fetch const shift for device
Error: Invalid index [0]
Error: Can't open device. 1.) is it plugged in? 2.) Read the README
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "9605019hsn2.py", line 64, in <module>
    depth = getDepthMap()
  File "9605019hsn2.py", line 42, in getDepthMap
    depth, timestamp = freenect.sync_get_depth()
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable
```

Answer (score 1):

Obviously, `freenect.sync_get_depth()` returns `None`, and when you try to store this into `depth, timestamp` it fails, since `None` is not iterable.

Refactor this code, and do proper error handling:

```
d = freenect.sync_get_depth()
if d is not None:
    depth, timestamp = d
else:
    error()
```